Help identifying I2C sensor from Propel Star Wars Drone
I have a sensor from a Propel Star Wars drone that I can't identify. The metal part of the sensor is marked with "A6103 040". I have tried various libraries and sensors, including BME280, BMP280, BMP388, BME680, MPU6050, MS5611, HTU21D, LPS22HB, and MS8607, but none have worked. Does anyone have an idea what sensor this could be, or has experience with similar sensors used in Propel drones?
The sensor has an I2C address of 0x76 and shows the following register values:
| Register | Value  |
|----------|--------|
| 0x00     | 0xCA   |
| 0x01     | 0x4E   |
| 0x02     | 0xA4   |
| 0x03     | 0x21   |
| 0x04     | 0xD0   |
| 0x05     | 0xBC   |
| 0x06     | 0x03   |
| 0x07     | 0x83   |
| 0x08     | 0xC7   |
| 0x09     | 0x00   |
| 0x0A     | 0x00   |
| 0x0B     | 0x00   |
| 0x0C     | 0x00   |
| 0x0D     | 0x10   |
| 0x0E     | 0x00   |
| 0x0F     | 0x00   |
| 0x10     | 0x0D   |
| 0x11     | 0x0E   |
| 0x12     | 0xFA   |
| 0x13     | 0x12   |
| 0x14     | 0xDE   |
| 0x15     | 0xBF   |
| 0x16     | 0x36   |
| 0x17     | 0x35   |
| 0x18     | 0xF4   |
| 0x19     | 0xFB   |
| 0x1A     | 0x04   |
| 0x1B     | 0x3E   |
| 0x1C     | 0xDF   |
| 0x1D     | 0xEB   |
| 0x1E     | 0x00   |
| 0x1F     | 0x3C   |
| 0x20     | 0xFC   |
| 0x21     | 0x2B   |
| 0x22     | 0x00   |
| 0x24     | 0x20   |
| 0x25     | 0x57   |
| 0x26     | 0x62   |
| 0x27     | 0xA6   |
| 0x28     | 0x32   |
| 0x29     | 0x00   |
| 0x2A     | 0x00   |
| 0x2B     | 0x00   |
| 0x2C     | 0x00   |
| 0x2D     | 0x00   |
| 0x2E     | 0x00   |
| 0x2F     | 0x00   |
| 0x30     | 0x61   |
| 0x31     | 0x14   |
| 0x32     | 0x02   |
| 0x33     | 0x66   |
| 0x34     | 0x97   |
| 0x35     | 0x0D   |
| 0x36     | 0x00   |

Here are some photos of the sensor and the board:



Thinking about the sensors a drone might have, maybe it's an accelerometer. Do the values change if you change the orientation of the device?

Hey Andrew,
yes the values changes but I recently found out: It is an Altimeter SPL06-001. Thank you

Strictly speaking, it is not an Altimeter, it is a pressure sensor used as an Altimeter.

Might be a pressure sensor like the Goertek SPL06-001. It's probably used to measure the altitude of the drone.
It uses the I²C address 0x76 if the SDO pin is pulled to ground according to the datasheet.


(Source: lcsc.com)

Hi Nanash1,
I wanted to thank you for your invaluable assistance in identifying the sensor from my Propel Star Wars drone. With this information, I was able to proceed with the correct setup and implementation.
20:22:58.391 -> Measured Air Pressure: 979.22 mb
20:22:58.391 -> Local Airport Sea Level Pressure: 1011.30 mb
20:22:58.391 -> altitude: 271.1 m
20:22:58.391 -> altitude: 889.4 ft
Your help has been much appreciated, and I’m grateful for your guidance.
How could you identify it really quickly? It is impressing!

I won't speak for @nanash1 who obviously is skilled in recognising components, but the shape of the can of the sensor is very much typical of a mems pressure sensor or microphone (same same but different). So the type is not too tough to guess. Then I would say its a matter of knowing where to search for what and make some educated guesses and finally check datasheets
